# 2008 honda accord

Tags: honda, accord, no-crank-no-start

i was driving and the car was driving fine out of no where the car started jerking and the lights started flashing in the dash board and the check engine light came on and the car shut off i baught a new fuel pump its not that i have no communication from obd port it turns it on but it reads error i have a 2008 honda accord 4 cylinder its killing me what can it be its not the altinator cause i put a new battery in the car and still nothing please i really need help i put starting fluid to see nothing

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Try a different code reader. If that doesn't work (you still come up with the error), I'd consider there's an issue with the Engine Control Module (ECM). Don't just exchange to a different ECM ... prove it out first. You should be able to get comms. The reason your reader is able to power up is because there is a power pin in the OBDII port which comes from the battery.

Comment: Make sure to confirm you have over 12V at the battery, ecm input and obd2 port. Honda modules like to not come online for much under 11.5V. Just because your tool is powered does not mean you have enough voltage.

Comment: i put a new battery on it it s enough power but its still saying error on the machines can it be the main relay